# How do I use a matrix inverse to solve this linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given matrix A, and asked to find its inverse, and then using my answer to that, solve a similar linear system.

(a)
$$
A =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2 & -1 \\
    -4 & -5 & 7 \\
    1 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Finding the inverse gave me:
$$
A^{-1} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 1 & 9 \\
    3 & -1 & -10 \\
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the problem says:

(b) Use the answer from part (a) to solve the linear system

$$2x_1+2x_2-x_3=2$$
$$-4x_1-5x_2+7x_3=4$$
$$x_1+x_2-x_3=-4$$

I could solve this system using Gauss-Jordan Elimination, but we don't get full credit unless we solve the problem the way it specifies, and I just don't see how to use the inverse of A to solve for x1, x2, and x3. Any help to send me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** $$A^{-1}AX = X = A^{-1}b$$

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the hint! It put me on the right path to find out what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Moo for the hint to set me on the right path! Once I realized what I needed to do, I set up the matrix equality of 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 1 & 9 \\
    3 & -1 & -10 \\
    1 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}*
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    4\\
    -4\\
    \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2\\
    x_3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

And when I multiplied the matricies I found the values:
$$x_1=-36$$
$$x_2=42$$
$$x_3=10$$

Which were my expected answers I got from using Gauss-Jordan Elimination.